# Tag Editing - Process?

Tags: discussion, tags

There was a tag that I thought was a meta tag here on Super User. I clicked on it, then looked through the questions. Some are tagged properly with it, but others (many others) are using the tag almost as part of a sentence. Is there already a process in place, possibly in the Tag Cleanup, where it could be added and have people edit the tag out of questions where it is not appropriate?

The tag in question is [system](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system).

Comment: It's a horrible tag and it should probably be removed

Comment: An edit on this question 15 hours ago and [an edit here](http://meta.superuser.com/posts/5718/revisions). Quite a cooincidence @sathya

Comment: @Raystafarian Sneaky sneaky...